# How to create online file server for students

Tags: ftp, webserver, file-sharing, upload, file-server

I would like to make a page for my students group, requirements:

- someone with account (login and password, which me, admin, would give them)
- those with access, can upload and download files

How can I make it? Can I do this without using my PC to be "server" and there will be no need to have it running all day? If you can, please just give me some keywords so I can google them and maybe even implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to use one of the collaborative cloud spaces that are out there. Popular choices are Google Drive, MS Azure, Amazon and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in hosting an actual website which includes upload and download capabilities, you might want to look into a low-cost (or free) hosting service [such as the ones listed in this article](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/free-web-hosting/). While file-sharing isn't their primary purpose, it can be done, especially with either the allowed FTP accounts in any given package or through web scripts (check carefully with your provider on what they support).

If all you need is "another computer" to setup an FTP server on, you could try a low-cost "virtual private server" (anywhere from $5-$30 a month on average) which essentially acts as a barebones computer (you install and/or configure all your necessary software).

In either case, you may want also have a look at [ownCloud](https://owncloud.com/), which provides a Dropbox-like service (including multiple users) which you can download and set up on a server of your own choosing for free. Assuming you don't wish to do this, they also have an [online service](https://owncloud.com/pricing/) which runs ownCloud as a service for money.